# ASP.NET to Akka through Azure/AWS message queue

Tags: architecture, akka, distributed, multiplayer

I'm completely new to distributed application design and am trying to do this test application to get some understanding on how it all works together. Thus I would appreciate any feedback on the following application design.

**Problem:**

Design a turn-based multiplayer game.

**Possible implementation:**

I'm thinking of the following high-level implementation/workflow:

`Client (Mobile/Web/etc) <-> SignalR ASP MVC website <-> Azure/AWS MQ <-> Akka actors <-> DB`

Each connected client will have a corresponding `Player` actor in Akka backend.

All requests/responses for a client would go through SignalR ASP frontend and delegated through message queue to appropriate backend actors.

All moves/state queries to the game would be made by those `Player` actors to corresponding `Game` actor in backend which will handle updating game state in DB.

**Question:**

Does that design make sense? Is it a correct use-case for Akka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That design is certainly possible (I would not qualify use-cases as correct or incorrect), although SignalR/Azure/DB are not a priori necessary components: you could also build the front-end using [Play framework](http://www.playframework.com/) (for example), use [Akka Cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC2/scala/cluster-usage.html) and [Distributed PubSub](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC2/contrib/distributed-pub-sub.html) for messaging and [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC2/scala/persistence.html) for storing the game world’s state. But any mix you might choose should work just fine. You can take a look at the [Reactive Maps](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-maps) tutorial in [Activator](http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted) if you are interested in how it looks like to go “all in” with Akka.